# The `or` operator on dict.keys()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

As I've been unable to find any documentation on this, so I'll ask here.

As shown in the code below, I found that the `or` operator (`|`), worked as such:

```
a = {"a": 1,"b": 2, 2: 3}
b = {"d": 10, "e": 11, 11: 12}

keys = a.keys() | b.keys()
aonce = a.keys() | a.values()
bonce = b.keys() | b.values()

for i in keys:
    print(i, end=" ")
print()
for i in aonce:
    print(i, end=" ")
print()
for i in bonce:
    print(i, end=" ")
print()
```

Which produces the result, in some order:

```
2 d 11 a b e   
3 1 2 a b   
10 e 11 12 d
```

Initially I assumed these iterable was compatible with `|`, similar to the way sets are, however. Testing with other iterable, such as a `list.__iter__()`, threw an error. Even;

```
values = a.values() | b.values()
for i in values:
    print(i, end=" ") 
print()
```

Which I'd assume worked, due to the use of `dict.values()` in the previous examples, threw an error.

So, my question is; What on earth have I come across, and more importantly, how reliable is it? What subclass does my arguments need to be, for me to be able to use this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Python 3 Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) notes that the `dict.keys` method is set-like and implements [`collections.abc.Set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Set).

Note that `dict.values` is **not set-like** even though it might appear to be so in your examples:

```
aonce = a.keys() | a.values()
bonce = b.keys() | b.values()
```

However these are leveraging off the fact that the keys view implements `__or__` (and `__ror__`) over arbitrary iterables.

For example, the following will not work:

```
>>> a.values() | b.values()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'dict_values' and 'dict_values'
```